# Add to User.Identity another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Add to `User.Identity`  a property like `User.Identity.PermissionLevel`.

### The problem

I don't know where to start. Can someone give me some ideas?

### The scenario

As I said, I want to extend for `Identity` the `PermissionLevel` property. I often use this property and I don't want to execute a SQL operation just to bring to me the authenticated user's permission for obvious reasons (performance, redundancy, etc.).

### Knowledge

`User.Identity.Name` is already populated with the email that the user entered to authenticate with the application.

### Bonus question

And what if I want to change `User.Identity.Name` during application? I mean, and what if in a special moment I want to change the `User.Identity.Name` from email to user's name?

Comment: You can try to extend the IdentityProvider to implement your own inplace of the default implementation that comes with ASP.Net

Comment: Look into using roles, which are built in to the authentication/authorization system.

Comment: You shouldn't cache security decisions.  (This includes "PermissionLevel" and Roles.)  Those could change while the user is logged in and should take effect immediately.

Comment: @zimdanen What would do I do, then?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge:  You should get the roles/permissions anew for every request.

Comment: So, @Zimdanen, the solution is bring the `PermissionLevel` from the database?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge:  Well, they should come from your permissions data store somehow; doesn't have to be a direct call to the store by your code.  (For example, you could use the ASP.NET Roles Provider.)

Comment: Just to clarify, @zimdanen: the role provider acts differently than identity provider? I ask this because it isn't unsecure to use this type of provider to store the `PermissionLevel` of someone?

Answer (score 0):

You should examine ASP.NET Membership and Profile providers. Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) where it is explained in detail.

User.Identity.Name will have whatever the user input on authentication (email or username, depending on your code).